# Some confusion about "One to Many" relationship

Tags: database, one-to-many, diagram, er-diagram

Please have a look at the below diagram image.

[image]

That image represents the "One to Many" relationship. It says "Client is introduced by Introducer". Client can have 1 Introducer or non at all, but Intrudcer can have many clients.

So even though it is "*Client can have 1 Introducer or **non** at all*", it is still described in ER Diagrams as a one to many relationship right? I am little worried about this "**non at all**" part, as far as I know "One to many relationship" describes that scenario as well. I am bit confused on this, having a look at diagrams after some time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-to-many relations only states (in your example diagram) that ONE client could have only ONE introducer (this is the ONE part of the One-to-many). (A client could be introduced by only one introducer).
The MANY part states that one Introducer could introduce zero, one or any number of clients.
A client can contact you without any introduction.

You are right, the one-to-many relationship could be confusing, but is there any relationship if there is no introducer for a client? (No there is no relation).

In the above example, if the `Introducer_id` column in the `Client` table is nullable, the relationship is not a requirement, so there could be one or more clients who has no introducer.
The relationship could be required, if the foreign key column is not nullable (The `NOT NULL` constraint is present on the field).

So the relationship and its cardinality is defined by the `FOREIGN KEY` and the `NOT NULL` constraints on the 'many' side's columns.

The ER diagram represents the cardinality of the relationship when the relationship actually exists. (How can you represent that there is no relation?)

Comment: awesome answer. `A client can contact you without any introdution` - This is what I exactly wanted to know. `In the above example, if the Introducer_id column in the Client table is nullable, the relationship is not a requirement, so there could be one or more clients who has no introducer.` - Yes it is Nullable.  Thanks a lot~

Comment: `Only one person can introduce a new person` - Introducer can introduce many clients...Not just one..

Comment: This is bit confusing.. `Only one person can introduce a new person ` -because introducer can have many clients.

Comment: That is true, but one client (new person) could be introduced by one introducer :)  I'll edit the answer as soon as possible. (I'm on phone now)